# How there are 7 enolizable hydrogens in 2‐methylcyclohex‐2‐en‐1‐one?

Tags: organic-chemistry, isomers

> **49.** How many enolizable hydrogens are there in the following compound?
>
> [image: 2‐methylcyclohex‐2‐en‐1‐one]
>
> (**a**) 2
> (**b**) 4
> (**c**) 5
> (**d**) 7

I know that enolate ion is the anion formed when an α-hydrogen in the molecule of an aldehyde or ketone is removed as a hydrogen ion.

In the above question I find only two α-hydrogens which can participate (denoted with red color):

[image: 2‐methylcyclohex‐2‐en‐1‐one with α-hydrogens]

But the answer is (**d**) 7.
Where am I getting wrong?

Comment: How about the protons on the Me group?

Comment: I don't see how the protons in the methyl group could be involved.

Comment: @J_B892 That's what TAR86 mentioned (γ not para position as ring isn't aromatic).

Comment: Enolizable with what? With a base such as hydroxide, the answer is 4. Two α- hydrogens and two vinylogous hydrogens at the γ-position.

Comment: I think there is a mistake in the question; the structure should be 3‐methylcyclohex‐2‐en‐1‐one.

Answer (score -1):

Actually there are exactly 7 alpha hydrogen in the given structure.  Just look that there is also a double bond and it is also considered as functional group.  So, you should count alpha hydrogen w.r.t  double bond and they are 5 .

Finally 2 + 5 you get the required answer = 7

Comment: Look, that's just wrong. You can't deprotonate the methyl group and delocalise the negative charge onto oxygen.